# property selected spark button

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flex4, flex3

I can't retrieve an equivalent to selected button on spark .

A bit of code:

`_selectedBtn.selected=false;`

Please any idea?

Answer (score 5):

Use a `ToggleButton` instead.
Or you could implement your own `button.selected` behavior.

Answer (score 0):

> In MX, you create a toggle button by setting the toggle property of
>   the MX Button control to true. in Spark, the ToggleButton is a
>   separate component.
>
> The Button control is a commonly used rectangular button. Button
>   controls look like they can be pressed, and have a text label, an
>   icon, or both on their face. You can optionally specify graphic skins
>   for each of several Button states.
>
> You can create a normal Button control or a ToggleButton control. A
>   normal Button control stays in its pressed state for as long as the
>   mouse button is down after you select it. A ToggleButton stays in the
>   pressed state until you select it a second time.

Quoted from http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=controls_04.html